# Spring 3.5 Security

Tags: spring, spring-security

Form based Authentication for Spring based Application 
I need to design Login page such way that Authentication upon login user and subsequent web request will validate if user is logged or not and redirect to the login page if not logged in .   This is classical web application login flow.   The authentication needs to be done via custom logic (application specific).
Can you provide sample Spring configuration 3.5 or working  example application does this ?  One approach is do login check via Web Filter and have login controller.  Is there a better way doing via Spring Security model  ?  Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Bmis13

Comment: There is no Spring Securiy 3.5 or Spring 3.5 at the moment. The actual version of Spring Security is 3.1, the actual version of Spring (core) is 3.1 too.

Answer (score 1):

The default way would be to use the spring securtiy filter chain.

Spring Security has already everything to do form based authentication, the only thing you need to do is

- configure it
- write an jsp page (with the two input fields for user name and password)

See this create article: http://www.mularien.com/blog/2008/07/07/5-minute-guide-to-spring-security/  it explain the first steps.

And have a look at this article too: http://www.mkyong.com/spring-security/spring-security-form-login-example/ - It set some default values (urls) this make it more clear how the filters works.